# htmlentities() não funciona

Tags: php

Olá,

Estou a guardar código HTML numa variável de sessão:

```
$_SESSION["recuperarInvalido"] = "<p id='recuperarInvalido'> O e-mail introduzido é inválido! </p>";
```

Mas ao escrever o valor da variável de sessão:

```
echo htmlentities($_SESSION["recuperarInvalido"]);
```

No browser aparece assim:

```
<p id='recuperarInvalido'> O e-mail introduzido é inválido! </p>
```

Mas deveria aparecer assim:

```
O e-mail introduzido é inválido!
```

Comment: já iniciou a sessão? `session_start();`

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO Sim, está iniciada.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $_SESSION["recuperarInvalido"];
```

apenas remova o "htmlentities()", pois ele foi feito para converter o html em string, para mostrar literalmente o html no front!

Answer (score 2):

Miguel,

dei uma pesquisada aqui, e de acordo com o [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp) a função `htmlentities` é utilizada para justamente fazer o contrário do que você deseja. Ela foi feita para que uma String seja completamente exibida pelo navegador, não importa qual seja o seu conteudo. Sendo assim os char `<` e `>` são convertidos em `&lt;` e `&gt;` e não são interpretados pelo navegador como tags html e sim como texto.

Para obter o que você quer, simplesmente remova a função `htmlentities`:

```
echo $_SESSION["recuperarInvalido"];
```

Contudo, devo te alertar que isso irá funcionar, mas não é a melhor aproximação. 
Acredito que não é uma boa prática escrever código HTML no backend, normalmente deixo o HTML para o arquivo de template.

O usuário [Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/39041/guilherme-spinxo) postou uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118447/14711) logo abaixo que deixa o código php do seu backend, mais separado do seu código HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Vejamos, você poderia armazenar os valores da sessão em uma variável `$session`

```
$session = $_SESSION["recuperarInvalido"] = 'O e-mail introduzido é inválido!';
```

Aqui você verifica se existe a `$_SESSION['recuperarInvalido']`, se existir ai sim você manda o navegador renderizar.

```
<?php
        if (isset($session)) {
        ?>
            <p id='recuperarInvalido'> ><?php echo $session; ?> </p> 
    <?php } ?>
```

Deste modo eu acho mais prático.